# How useful is polynomial regression in machine learning as polynomial equations of degree >=2 have more than one solution?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

What if different inputs give the same output as non-linear equations have more than one roots?
Also, can multiple entirely different weight values give approximately the same optimal predictions? 
For example,

```
length = 1000
X = np.random.rand(length,1) * 100 
plt.plot(X,3.5*(X**2) + 3.45*X + 3.44,"g.",alpha = 0.8)
plt.plot(X,3.60818952*(X**2)-5.94902958*X  -17.74136614,"y.")
plt.show()
```

gives the same curves.
[matplotlib graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC6Ht.png)

Comment: Try plotting the *difference* in the two equations. The scale of your plot is obscuring the difference, making it difficult to see.